# Unable to parse RFC6587 framed syslog from PulseSecure using syslog-ng OSE 3.33

Tags: parsing, syslog-ng

PulseSecure devices are sending syslog conform RFC5424. When TCP is used as transport, RFC6587 framing is prepended to the syslog message (MSG_LEN SP SYSLOG_MSG).
I also need to receive syslog on same TCP port without RFC6587 framing, so the syslog source is not an option to use as that expects the framing to be present at all times.
What I tried is to use network driver and disable parsing using flags(no-parse), and have a rewrite rule to remove the RFC6587 framing. The rewrite rule works - framing is indeed removed.
But when I try to parse the message with the syslog-parser it does not seem to work; e.g. hostname is not extracted (IP address is used).
I try to use regular expression matching to recognize RFC5424 or RFC3164 syslog which does not work either; it always ends up on the "else" part of the if construction. Even removing the if construction does not help (forcing to use the rfc5424 parser).

Test configuration is as follows (I use TCP/602 for testing):

```
source s_net_tcp602 {
  network(
    port(602)
    transport("tcp")
    flags(no-parse)           # Store entire message into MESSAGE/MSG macro
    flags(store-raw-message)  # Store original message in RAWMSG macro
  );
};

# RFC6587 framing: MSG_LEN SP SYSLOG-MSG
# This rewrite rule removes the MSG_LEN SP completely from MESSAGE macro if present
rewrite rw_remove_rfc6587_framing {
  subst(
    "^\d+\s+<",      # Matches digits followed by one or more spaces and '<' bracket  at start of MESSAGE
    "<",             # Replace with only '<' bracket so effectively RFC6587 framing removed
    value("MESSAGE")
  );
};

parser p_syslog_rfc3164 {
  syslog-parser(
    drop-invalid(no)
    flags(validate-utf8)
    template("${MESSAGE}")
  );
};

parser p_syslog_rfc5424 {
  syslog-parser(
    flags(syslog-protocol)
    drop-invalid(no)
    flags(validate-utf8)
    template("${MESSAGE}")
  );
};

destination d_test_5424 { file("/var/log/test5424/${S_YEAR}_${S_MONTH}_${S_DAY}_${HOST}.log" template("${MESSAGE}\n") perm(0644) create_dirs(yes)); };
destination d_test_3164 { file("/var/log/test3164/${S_YEAR}_${S_MONTH}_${S_DAY}_${HOST}.log" template("${MESSAGE}\n") perm(0644) create_dirs(yes)); };

log {

  # Complete message should be stored in MESSAGE and RAWMSG macro
  source(s_net_tcp602);

  # Strip MSG_LEN part from MESSAGE if it matches RFC6587 framing and continue
  rewrite(rw_remove_rfc6587_framing);

  # MESSAGE macro now contains either RFC3164 or RFC5424 formatted message

  # Use If mechanism to determine if MESSAGE conforms to RFC5424 or RFC3164
  # Using two different destinations to allow determining result of regular expression matching
  if (message('^<\d+>\d+\s')) {
    parser(p_syslog_rfc5424);
    destination(d_test_5424);
  } else {
    parser(p_syslog_rfc3164);
    destination(d_test_3164);
  };

};
```

Example syslog message from PulseSecure:

```
196 <134>1 2022-03-29T10:38:05+02:00 hostname PulseSecure: - - - 2022-03-29 10:38:05 - ive - <REMOVED MSG>
```

It might be that this is an obvious mistake I am making, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction...

Thanks in advance,
Marco

I tried to remove the RFC6587 framing using rewrite rule which seems to work, but afterwards the message is not successfully parsed by the syslog-parser.
I also tried to send syslog from another device (CitrixADC) to the same destination, and it seems that parsing is tried but fails as probably CitrixADC syslog does not fully comply to RFC3164.
Tried to remove the if-else construction completely and forcing the RFC5424 parsing without success.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was able to solve this issue using Junction/Channels with dedicated filters to recognize RFC3164 or RFC5424 formatted syslog.
Still testing, but the hostname is now correctly parsed from RFC5424 formatted syslog with RFC6587 framing from PulseSecure appliances.

Current sample configuration which seem to work:

```
source s_net_tcp602 {
  network(
    port(602)
    transport("tcp")
    flags(no-parse)           # Store entire message into MESSAGE/MSG macro
    flags(store-raw-message)  # Store original message in RAWMSG macro
  );
};

# RFC6587 framing: MSG_LEN SP SYSLOG-MSG
# This rewrite rule removes the MSG_LEN SP completely from MESSAGE macro if present
rewrite rw_remove_rfc6587_framing {
  subst(
    '^\d+\s+<',      # Matches digits followed by one or more spaces and '<' bracket  at start of MESSAGE
    '<',             # Replace with only '<' bracket so effectively RFC6587 framing removed
    value("MESSAGE"),
    flags("utf8")
  );
};

# Matches messages formatted according to RFC5424:
# PRI VERSION SP TIMESTAMP HOSTNAME SP APP-NAME SP PROCID SP MSGID SP STRUCTURED-DATA [SP MSG]
#   PRI is 1-3 digits between '<' and '>' brackets
#   VERSION is 0-2 digits so seems not to be mandatory? ==> We assume 1 or 2 digits
#   SP is a single whitespace
#
# Example start of message:
# <134>1 2022-03-29T14:33:18+02:00 hostname ...
filter f_rfc5424 {
  # PCRE-style regular expression
  # Using single quotes to prevent interpretation
  match('^<\d{1,3}>\d{1,2}\s' value("MESSAGE"));
};

# Matches messages formatted according to RFC3164:
# PRI TIMESTAMP SP HOSTNAME SP MSG
#   PRI       1-3 digits between '<' and '>' brackets
#   TIMESTAMP Local time in format "Mmm dd hh:mm:ss" (without the quotes)
#
# Example start of message:
# <134>Mar 29 14:33:18 hostname ...
filter f_rfc3164 {
  # PCRE-style regular expression
  # Using single quotes to prevent interpretation
  match('^<\d{1,3}>\D{3}\s' value("MESSAGE"));
};

parser p_syslog_rfc3164 {
  syslog-parser(
    drop-invalid(no)
    flags(validate-utf8)
    flags(sanitize-utf8)
    template("${MESSAGE}")
  );
};

parser p_syslog_rfc5424 {
  syslog-parser(
    flags(syslog-protocol)
    drop-invalid(no)
    flags(validate-utf8)
    flags(sanitize-utf8)
    template("${MESSAGE}")
  );
};

destination d_test_pre-parse { file("/var/log/test/preparse_${S_YEAR}_${S_MONTH}_${S_DAY}_${HOST}.log" template("${MESSAGE}\n") perm(0644) create_dirs(yes)); };
destination d_test_rfc5424 { file("/var/log/test/rfc5424_${S_YEAR}_${S_MONTH}_${S_DAY}_${HOST}.log" template("${RAWMSG}\n") perm(0644) create_dirs(yes)); };
destination d_test_rfc3164 { file("/var/log/test/rfc3164_${S_YEAR}_${S_MONTH}_${S_DAY}_${HOST}.log" template("${RAWMSG}\n") perm(0644) create_dirs(yes)); };
destination d_test_nonrfc { file("/var/log/test/nonrfc_${S_YEAR}_${S_MONTH}_${S_DAY}_${HOST}.log" template("${RAWMSG}\n") perm(0644) create_dirs(yes)); };

log {

  # Complete message should be stored in MESSAGE and RAWMSG macro as result of this source
  source(s_net_tcp602);

  # Strip MSG_LEN part from MESSAGE if it matches RFC6587 framing and continue
  rewrite(rw_remove_rfc6587_framing);

  # MESSAGE macro now contains either RFC3164 or RFC5424 formatted message
  destination(d_test_pre-parse);    # Just for testing, to be removed when done

  junction {
    # RFC5424 syslog
    channel {
      filter(f_rfc5424);
      parser(p_syslog_rfc5424);
      destination(d_test_rfc5424);
      flags(final);
    };
    # RFC3164 syslog
    channel {
      filter(f_rfc3164);
      parser(p_syslog_rfc3164);
      destination(d_test_rfc3164);
      flags(final);
    };
    # Non-RFC syslog
    channel {
      destination(d_test_nonrfc);
    };
  };
};
```